# sqlloader date conversion: inconsistent data type

Tags: oracle, sql-loader

Am trying to load some data to an Oracle database using SQLLoader but I keep getting the errors `ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected DATE got NUMBER` or `expecting char got date`

The date comes in the format of e.g. `20130815` and it is to be stored into a database with a column of type `Date`.

The logic should be that if someone passes an invalid date a `null` or say an invalid month in the date string e.g. `20131301`, then I want to insert a default date e.g. `19990101`.

Here is the SQLLoader code I have so far:

```
COLUMN_DOB   DATE 'YYYYMMDD' "CASE:COLUMN_DOB WHEN 'isdate(:COLUMN_DOB)=1' THEN :COLUMN_DOB ELSE to_date('19000101', 'YYYYMMDD') END",,
```

Comment: Does the error occur because of the code in the case statement? Because of the function call? What data type is being passed to the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The immediate issue is that you're calling `to_date()` on the fixed value. The `then` part is returning the original *string* value of the date from the file; the `else` is returning a `date`; which leads to the 'expecting char got date' message.

If you remove the `to_date()` part then it will load all the values as 1900-01-01, because you have the case statement wrong. You're comparing the `:COLUMN_DOB` value with the string `'isdate(:COLUMN_DOB)=1'`. It isn't calling the function, it's a fixed string, and your date field is never going to exactly match that text. So the `case` always goes into the `else` and gets the fixed value. You also seem to be mixing up the two forms of `case` statement.

So it should be:

```
... "CASE WHEN isdate(:COLUMN_DOB)=1 THEN :COLUMN_DOB ELSE '19000101' END"
```

Which, assuming you've built an `isdate()` function - since that is not an Oracle built-in - with a default format mask, something like this one [based on an AskTom version](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:890580198758):

```
create or replace function isdate (p_string in varchar2,
  p_fmt in varchar2 := 'YYYYMMDD')
return number as
  l_date date;
begin
  if l_date is null then
    return 0;
  end if;
  l_date := to_date(p_string, p_fmt);
  return 1;
exception
  when others then
     return 0;
end;
/
```

... will put in valid dates as supplied, and invalid dates as 1900-01-01. The null check also means nulls will be inserted as 1900-01-01; it's perhaps simpler to have it here than to try to handle that separately in the control file.

You could maybe simplify it further by having a function that tries to convert the string and returns a date, and just calling that in the control file, without the `date` mask or the `case` statement. That approach is covered in that AskTom link too.

Personally I'd probably prefer to see the column left null rather than giving it a magic number. It isn't impossible to have someone with a valid DOB of 1900-01-01.

---

If you are creating a new function anyway, you could do this instead:

```
create or replace function my2date(p_str in varchar2) return date is
begin
  return to_date(nvl(p_str, '19000101'), 'YYYYMMDD');
exception
  when others then -- just about acceptable here
    return date '1900-01-01';
end;
/
```

which you can execute from SQL*Plus, SQL Developer, Toad or whatever client you're using. And then you control file would have:

```
COLUMN_DOB "my2date(:COLUMN_DOB)"
```

I don't think there's a way of doing this without using a function. If you used an external table instead then you could use an anonymous block to do the conversion I suppose, but if you're stuck with SQL*Loader then I believe a function is the only way to stop a bad date causing the whole row to be rejected.

Comment: Thanks for feedback. I though the `isdate` function is an oracle function as seen [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/olap.111/b28126/dml_functions_1106.htm) so no, I don't have my own function created in Oracle and am not sure how to go about building one. Is there an alternative solution that doesn't involve creating the function?

Comment: @lukik - you can create a function, assuming you have permission, by connecting to SQL*PLus or your client of choice, as the same user you're running the load as, and just executing the `create or replace ...` statement. If you don't already have `isdate` then the `my2date` (also from Tom Kyte) is going to be cleaner I think.

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thanks. I created the a function and changed my control file to reflect the `my2date` function.